# SWT: How to find which item is selected?

Tags: java, swt

I have implemented a class like this:

```
public class ToolbarExample implement SelectionListener {
        ToolbarExample() {
                 //constructor ....

         openMenuItem.addSelectionListener(this);
         closeMenuItem.addSelectionListener(this);
        }

    @Override
public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
               switch(e.???) {
               case openMenu Selected: open(); break;
               case closeMenu Selected: close(); break;          
}
}
```

which method can I use with SelectionEvent? e.(???)

Updated:
after running Fred example code I debug the code, but e.item is null!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code gives you the selected widget.

```
e.item or e.getSource()
```

Sample

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
  Widget selectedItem = (e.item != null) ? e.item : e.getSource();
  if (selectedItem  == openMenu) {
    open();
  else if(selectedItem == closeMenu) {
    close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to case it? switch(e.item) { case what? } could you please lead with a simple code snnipet?

Comment: Switch case does not work on objects, why don't you use if statement?

Comment: This cause this error: The type Widget is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <?>.

Comment: Ok finally I find the solution, I correct your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4546/discussion-between-khajavi-and-fred)